# Coredata database prepopulation is not filled

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I'm trying to prepopulate a coredata database from a sqlite file, but I don't understand why the database is not filled. My sqlite file is properly filled with all the data I need and added in the bundle ressources.

Here the persistentStoreCoordinator method int the AppDelegate :

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
    {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }
    NSString    *storePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingString:@"MyApp.db"];
    NSError     *error = nil;

    NSFileManager   *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fm fileExistsAtPath:storePath])
    {
        NSString    *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyApp" ofType:@"db"];

        if (defaultStorePath)
        {
            [fm copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:storePath error:NULL];
        }
    }

    NSURL           *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:storePath];
    NSDictionary    *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

    persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error : %@: %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

In the view controller, I try to fetch the entries but it seems `enter code here`empty :

```
    NSManagedObjectContext  *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
initWithEntityName:@"Type_textimage_4text"];
    NSFetchRequest          *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription     *description = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Type_textimage_4text" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:description];


    NSMutableArray  *questions = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    NSLog(@"question : %@", questions);
```

I probably missed something but I don't find what. Anyone can help me please ?

Comment: I have 2 Apps wihch are delivered with prepopulated sqlite databases. I created them on an external DB manager. If you want to see what is happening on the DB, you can allways go to the folder where the simulator stores all the files and get the DB from there. Check it with and external App and you will see what's in there, independently from your code. Then you'll know where your problem is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I opened the DB with sqlite manager and I see my tables with all the entry I've put in but I see other tables I think created by CoreData write in uppercase. For example, I have a table type_textimage_4text created by me with all the values and a ZTYPE_TEXTIMAGE_4TEXT tables empty created by CoreData.

Comment: How can I import all my existing database in core-data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to the coment above, I'm adding the AppDelegate.m file of one App which includes a prepopulated sqlite database. To do that I selected "Use Core Data" when I created the project on xcode. Although it works for me, I believe it is now a better praxis to use NSDocument for this kind of applications. One of the advantages is that the project is already on a good track to be iCloud compatible. I haven't done that yet, so I'm speaking only from what I've read/seen.

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
// 
//
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainView.h"


@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UINavigationController *navViewController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;


        MainView *main=[[navViewController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];
        main.managedObjectContext=self.managedObjectContext;


    return YES;

}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application{
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{

}



- (void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {

            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        } 
    }
}

#pragma mark - Core Data stack








- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (__managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return __managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return __managedObjectContext;
}






// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }

    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Solvents" withExtension:@"momd"];



    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return __managedObjectModel;
}



- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectoryString {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return basePath;
}






- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Solvents.sqlite"];

    NSString *storePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectoryString] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Solvents.sqlite"];


    //NSLog(@"store path %@", storePath);
    //NSLog(@"store URL%@", storeURL );



    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storePath ]) {



        NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Solvents" ofType:@"sqlite"];


        if (defaultStorePath) {

            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:storePath error:NULL];
        }
    }




    NSError *error = nil;
    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {




        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}






#pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}




@end
```